# How to count unread messages in Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, messaging

I'm using the gem [mailboxer](https://github.com/ging/mailboxer).
Can anyone show me how to count the number of unread messages in inbox?

I tried:

```
<%= current_user.mailbox.inbox.unread.count %>
```

but I get

```
'ArgumentError in Messages#received wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With version 0.10 :

```
@user.mailbox.receipts.where(read:false).count
```

With version 0.11, I think it would be (tough I havn't tested it)

```
@user.mailbox.receipts.where(is_read:false).count
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking a look at the source code link provide by @MurifoX, i found this about the unread method:

```
current_user.unread_inbox_count
```

Gives you unread message inbox count.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at the source code, i found this about the `unread` method:

```
#Mark the object as unread for messageable.
def unread(obj)
  ...
end
```

All this method marks the message/mail as unread, intead of retrieving all unread messages.
Down the class i found this `def search_messages(query)` method that probably has something to do with your question.

Link to the class.
https://github.com/ging/mailboxer/blob/master/lib/mailboxer/models/messageable.rb

Comment: Thanks! I'm so newbie so that I think I cannot figure out how to make my own from source code. But Thanks:)

Comment: The name of the method is misleading tough

Answer (score 1):

I am using the version `0.9.x` of `mailboxer`. They renamed the corresponding database field from `read` to `is_read`. To count the unread messages of a user simply use:

```
@user.mailbox.receipts.where(:is_read => false).count
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this one worked best:

```
current_user.mailbox.inbox(:unread => true).count(:id, :distinct => true)
```